# Inserting audio on Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, audio

I'm making a website and I wanted to put an audio file on the page. The audio file is on google drive.  This is my code on html:

```
<audio src="https://googledrive.com/host/0B05vuZtkhYyvdXJJSmFKMGFDTWM/Stromae.mp3" ></audio>
```

'Stromae' is the name of the file
0B05vuZtkhYyvdXJJSmFKMGFDTWM is the id of the folder that contains the file.

When it runs, this is what appears in the console:

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (OK)"

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You didn't post any code.

Comment: `https://googledrive.com/host/0B05vuZtkhYyvdXJJSmFKMGFDTWM/Stromae.mp3` this link asks me to sign in and when I do it returns a 404. I think you just need to remake the link from your google drive. [Check out](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494822?hl=en) how to do that.

Comment: As it states in the error message - 404, means that the file cannot be found. This must be an invalid path.